# Download derived APK from new Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-play-console

I don't see the option to download the "Derivated APK" like in the old console when I publish a new version. I see the option to download the APK for one device but no the generic Derivated APK.

Where is the option?

Best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see the option to download the APK for one device

That's the one. It's just the same for all devices when you upload an APK (it can be different when you upload an App Bundle).